# BottleでWebページにHello Worldと表示できない。

Tags: python, bottle

#### 前提・実現したいこと

BottleでWebページに”Hello World”と表示したいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

①仮想環境を作成
②Bottleをインストール
③プログラム（以下に記載）を実行
④Bottleフレームワークの開発用サーバを起動
⑤Listening on htto://localhost:8000/と表示され、
URL部分をブラウザに入力すると、エラーになります。

コマンドプロントに以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
C:\Users\*****(本名)\Desktop\yasashiipython\pybotweb\lib\site- 
packages\bottle.py:3468:
Deprecation Warning: Flags not at the start of the expression
“((?m)[urbURB]?(?:’’(“ (truncated)
Patterns = [re.comple (p%pattern_vars) for p in patterns]
C:\Users\*****(本名)\Desktop\yasashiipython\pybotweb\env\lib\site- 
packages\bottle.py:3468:
DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression '\\[\\{((?:((? 
m)[urbURB'(truncated)
patterns = [re.compile(p&pattern_vars) for p in patterns]
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 22:2625] “GET / HTTP/1.1” 404 720
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 22:2625] “GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1” 404 742

sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=360, 
family=AddressFamily.AF_INET,type=Socketkind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr= 
('127.0.0.1', 8000)
```

ブラウザ上のエラー表示

```
Error: 404 Not Found
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/' caused an error:
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
from bottle import route, run


@route('/hello')
def hello():
return 'Hello World!'

run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=True)
```

#### 試したこと

このエラーが出現する前に、もう１つエラーが出ていました。
調べてみると、「マシン名が日本語の文字列だと発生するエラー」だったので、
マシン名を変更して、そのまま再起動しました。エラー名は控えていません。

ホスト名を8080、8000と試したが、エラー。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

windows8.1 64bit
Python3.6.5

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/125211

Answer (score 1):

ログを見るとBottleは動作していて、デバッガが不正なURLへのアクセスを検知しています。
`127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 22:2625] “GET / HTTP/1.1” 404 720`

[teratailの回答](https://teratail.com/questions/125211)と重複しますが、`@route('/hello')`と記述した場合、URLのPATHに/helloを指定する必要があります。
下記のURLにアクセスして`Hello World!`が表示されることを確認してください。

http://localhost:8000/hello

もしくは、下記のように`@route('/')`に書き換えることで http://localhost:8000/ で`Hello World!`を表示できます。

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=True)
```

[DeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning)は、Bottle内のコードで廃止予定の機能が使われたことによる警告です。
経験上、この警告が出ても私の環境ではBottle自体は動作しています。

Comment: payanecoさん、ご回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: エラーが出たら、Pythonの公式ドキュメントで調べることができるんですね、知らなかったです。

Comment: 使用している参考書では、単に@routeデコレータに’/hello’と指定するようにと書いてあったのですが、この部分をURLのPATHと呼ぶのですね。まだまだWEBに関して知らないので勉強します。